# Perl to Tcl code conversion

Tags: perl, tcl

I need to convert a perl script to a Tcl script. I have worked in Python before but this is a new challenge since I am novice in both perl and tcl.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how do I represent the following lines in Tcl:

```
my @GPO_regs = qw(0x70034 0x70038 0x7003C 0x70040 0x70044);

sub write_phy {
    my($phy, $register, $value) = @_;
    $value = oct($val) if $value =~ /^0/;
    if ($DEBUG) { printf("Write PHY ${phy} register ${register} =     
0x%0.8X\n", $value); };
    `./write_phy.pl ${phy} ${register} ${value}`;
}
```

And in another Perl file:

```
my ($phyAddr, $regAddr)  = @ARGV;

if($phyAddr =~ /0x/) {
   $phyAddr = oct($phyAddr);
}

 if($regAddr =~ /0x/) {
        $regAddr = oct($regAddr);
}


my $registerValue = 1 << 31 | $phyAddr << 25 | $regAddr << 20 | 2 << 1;
my $registerHex = sprintf("0x%X", $registerValue);

`./read_write_spi_reg -a 0x070064 -w ${registerHex}`;
my $value = `./read_write_spi_reg -a 0x070068 -r`;

if( $value >> 16 != 0 ) {
    die "Error reading PHY register";
 }
chomp($value);
printf("${value}\n");
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Your question is unsuited for Stack Overflow. You should start by trying out your luck and come back with specific questions. If you don't understand what the code does at all, look up all the keywords, then find equivalents. If you're a Python developer the actual program logic should not be a huge challenge. You will need to read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html to get started. You might want to write unit-tests (or something similar that just calls the program and checks output). Do it in Python. Run it against the Perl and the TCL you build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's consider your code in your first file:

```perl
my @GPO_regs = qw(0x70034 0x70038 0x7003C 0x70040 0x70044);
```

This (which is creating an effectively-global variable that is never used?) would be translated into:

```tcl
set GPO_regs {0x70034 0x70038 0x7003C 0x70040 0x70044}
```

Whereas this:

```perl
sub write_phy {
    my($phy, $register, $value) = @_;
    # Stuff...
}
```

Becomes:

```tcl
proc write_phy {phy register value} {
    # Translation of Stuff...
}
```

Going on to look at the contents of the subroutine (after applying the obvious correction):

```perl
$value = oct($value) if $value =~ /^0/;
```

This line decodes the octal value of a string if that string starts with a leading zero. Tcl does this by default in some contexts, but let's be explicit. I'll use a regular expression to do the “if that string starts with a leading zero” even though I would not normally do this, as that will help you translate your other file:

```tcl
if { [regexp {^0} $value] } {
    # The [scan] command is a lot like the C sscanf() function, if you know that
    scan $value "%o" value
}
```

The only tricky thing about translating this:

```perl
if ($DEBUG) { printf("Write PHY ${phy} register ${register} = 0x%0.8X\n", $value); };
```

is that Tcl has different variable scoping rules to Perl, so the `DEBUG` variable will be absent. In this case, the simplest technique is to use the fully-qualified name of the variable.

```tcl
if {$::DEBUG} {
    puts [format "Write PHY ${phy} register ${register} = 0x%0.8X" $value]
    ### However, I recommend this instead:
    # puts [format "Write PHY %s register %s = 0x%0.8X" $phy $register $value]
    ### As unexpected % symbols in phy or register won't make it choke. The equivalent
    ### advice would apply if you were sticking with Perl.
}
```

Finally, the backticks in Perl translate pretty directly to Tcl's `exec`, so this:

```perl
`./write_phy.pl ${phy} ${register} ${value}`;
```

Becomes this:

```tcl
exec ./write_phy.pl $phy $register $value
```

You can usually omit the `{`braces`}` from around Tcl variable names; you only need them where it would lead to an otherwise-unwanted parse.

Putting this all together, I get:

```tcl
set GPO_regs {0x70034 0x70038 0x7003C 0x70040 0x70044}

proc write_phy {phy register value} {
    if { [regexp {^0} $value] } {
        scan $value "%o" value
    }
    if {$::DEBUG} {
        puts [format "Write PHY %s register %s = 0x%0.8X" $phy $register $value]
    }
    exec ./write_phy.pl $phy $register $value
}
```

---

Note that the code in the other file has some nasty bugs lurking! I won't go into depth about it, but the key things you need to know are that expressions that are not used as `if` conditions should be wrapped in `expr`, like this:

```
set registerValue [expr {1 << 31 | $phyAddr << 25 | $regAddr << 20 | 2 << 1}]
```

and the recommended way of splitting the arguments to a script into variables is like this:

```
lassign $argv phyAddr regAddr
```

(Tcl's `$` doesn't mean “this is a variable”, it means “read from this variable”. Variable *names* passed to things that manipulate the variable itself — e.g., `set` and `lassign` — should not normally have a `$` in front.)

Also, Perl's `die` is a lot like Tcl's `error`, and Tcl's `exec` automatically does a `chomp`-like operation on it's result.

Comment: The time and effort you gave to write the above post...I have no words...thanks a lot...that's all what I can say !!